# Error when setting variable as a result of other variables and numbers in a loop

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

In the script below where I count filetypes and then perform a ffmpeg on all those files I try to echo a progress of sorts but when setting the `pprog`:

```
@echo on & setlocal

set count=0
set pattern=*.mp4
set pattern0=*.webm
for /f %%i in ('dir /b /a-d %pattern% ^| find /c /v ""') do @call set count=%%i
for /f %%i in ('dir /b /a-d %pattern0% ^| find /c /v ""') do @call set count0=%%i
set sum=%count% + %count0%
set total=%sum%
FOR /r %%i in (*.mp4,*.webm) DO (
set /A pprog=((100-%sum%)*100) / (%count%+%count0%)
set /A sum=%sum% - 1
echo %pprog% done %sum% files left out of %total%
)
pause
```

I get this error:

```
*100 is unexpected at this time.
```

I understand that anything after the first closing parentheses is not properly recognized and it throws the next thing after it as `"X" was unexpected.`
The result from `set /A pprog=((100-%sum%)*100) / (%count%+%count0%)` should be a normal number,the calcualtion is wrong ignore it , it doesnt change the issue, the whole output is this:

```
E:\Desktop\New folder>test2.bat
E:\Desktop\New folder>set count=0
E:\Desktop\New folder>set pattern=*.mp4
E:\Desktop\New folder>set pattern0=*.webm
E:\Desktop\New folder>for /F %i in ('dir /b /a-d *.mp4 | find /c /v ""') do @call set count=%i
File Not Found
E:\Desktop\New folder>for /F %i in ('dir /b /a-d *.webm | find /c /v ""') do @call set count0=%i
E:\Desktop\New folder>set sum=0 + 10
E:\Desktop\New folder>set total=0 + 10
*100) was unexpected at this time.
E:\Desktop\New folder>set /A pprog=((100-0 + 10)*100) / (0+10)
E:\Desktop\New folder>
```

The file not found is not an issue. Just use the numbers here if you want to experiment.
Edited to remove `rem` lines and rerun the script and updated the output.
Edited to add more explanation to the error.

Comment: [delayed expansion problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282784/variables-are-not-behaving-as-expected/30284028#30284028)

Comment: Irrespective of any variable expansion issue, there are many more problems with this script. The most important being that you have far more closing parentheses than opening ones; you have used `set` rather than `set /a`; many of your `set /a` commands should be double-quoted; you need to change how you are representing your variables in your `set /a` commands!

Comment: @Compo Thx is there a good book for batch that may also  include everything you mentioned?

Comment: It wouldn't be right for me to advise on books or other reference sources to assist you, as such questions are off topic on StackOverflow. Also, as you've not even attempted to explain what the code is supposed to be doing, and that code is too poor for me to even begin with advising you on the best ways to fix or improve it.

Comment: There are many recommended links (including a book) in the tag info: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/batch-file/info

Comment: @Compo But I did explain it at the start, it counts files by some pattern for filetypes then while I do an ffmpeg conversion on them it counts down giving me a progress message, so that I know how many of those files have completed conversion and how many are still not done.

Comment: Why are you counting flles in `E:\Desktop\New folder`? then processing files within that directory and every one of its subdirectories? Surely your percentage calculation, (I presume that's what you're doing as a 'progress'), will not be accurate unless the count is taken from the same listing.

Comment: @Compo Yes its a percentage. You are correct I forgot to count the subdirs too with FOR /R.

Comment: The `For /R` already recurses the subdirectories. Either the `For /R` should just be a `For` or the `Dir` counting would require a subdirectory recursion option. If you open a Command Prompt window, type `dir /?`, and press the `[ENTER]` key, you should learn how that can be achieved. Whilst you're at it you can also learn about your other commands too, e.g. `set /?`, `for /?`, `find /?`, `call /?`.

Comment: so the for /r option wont work for the pattern matching counter?/F doesnt search subdirs but /r does, from whatt I understand.

Comment: I asked you, and shouldn't have to repeat it, to "open a Command Prompt window, type `dir /?`, and press the `[ENTER]` key". _Continuing to misread, or ignore, advice is not going to somehow lure me into rewriting your code for you, or becoming your personal tutor for the entire task_.

Comment: __"The result should be a normal number, instead the whole output is this:"__ because you've set `@echo on` when it should be `off`. The `unexpected ` message is because of  closing parentheses inside a `for` code block. You need to escape them with a caret.

Comment: @theo1996, you appear to have now removed content from your code. Please run the new code and ensure that the rest of your content reflects that modification. _Your 'whole output' is certainly no longer valid, for instance_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, there are a few issues with your code (both syntax-wise and logical). Here is a revised version:

```
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "count=0"
set "pattern=*.mp4"
set "pattern0=*.webm"
for /f %%i in ('dir /b /s  /a-d "%pattern%" "%pattern0%" ^| find /c /v ""') do set "total=%%i"
set "counter=0"
FOR /r %%i in ("%pattern%","%pattern0%") DO (
  set /A count+=1
  set /A pprog=count*100/total
  echo !pprog!%% - !count! files of %total% done. (%%i)
)
```

Comment: Thank you, I didnt know I can put 2 patterns in the `for /f` command. Your version is much cleaner.

Comment: There needs to be a space between /b and /s in the `for /f`.

Comment: not really necessary (aka it works without a space), but yes, best practice to separate the switches. Edited. The "2 patterns" are a thing of `dir`, not of `for`

Comment: I meant the `for /f` line,my mistake, weird I run it without the spaces and it didnt work, but I run again and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

I couldnt find the specific reason why you need to use quotes on `set /a` when doing multiplication. `set /?` says you need to use quotes only with logical and modulus operators. I read several books on beginner and advanced batch scripting and they dont explain it either. Apparently its an unwritten rule,found it on ss64, to always use quotes with `set /a` and there is the trick of putting the opening quote before the equal sign instead of before the variable to be set. Added the `/s` option to the `dir` to count subfolders too.

```
@echo on & setlocal & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion. 

set count=0
set pattern=*.mp4
set pattern0=*.webm
for /f %%i in ('dir /s /b /a-d %pattern% ^| find /c /v ""') do @call set count=%%i
for /f %%i in ('dir /s /b /a-d %pattern0% ^| find /c /v ""') do @call set count0=%%i
set /A sum"=count+count0"
echo %sum%
set total=!sum!
echo %total%
echo %count%
echo %count0%
FOR /r %%i in (*.mp4,*.webm) DO ( 
ffmpeg -i "%%~fi" -threads 3 -c:v  hevc "%%~dpni.mkv"
set /A sum"-=1"
set /A pprog"=100-(!sum!*100 /(!count!+!count0!))"
echo "!pprog!%% done (!sum! files left out of %total%)"
title "!pprog!%% done (!sum! files left out of %total%)"
)
pause
```

Escaping the parenthesis, as someone commented, doesnt work.

I can also use title to show it at the window title for clarity.

Comment: Escaping parenthesis does work, you need to escape the correct ones though.

Comment: the quotes are not for the sake of `set /a`, but to make the parentheses safe (quoted strings are parsed differently). Suggested syntax `set /A "pprog=100-(!sum!*100 /(!count!+!count0!))"` etc. (note the location of the quotes)

Comment: @Gerhard I tried escaping the first closing parentheses with ^ and it didnt work.Maybe you meant something else?